# Input attribute required is affecting css transition

Tags: html, css

I have some inputs styled by CSS and on one input I need to remove the attribute required. For some reason, this changes how the CSS animations behave. When the attribute required is added to an input, it changes the way the animations behave.

Any solution?

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" class="form-input" autofocus required>
<span class="highlight"></span>
<span class="bar"></span>
<label class="form-label">Name</label>
```

```
<input type="text" class="form-input" autofocus>
<span class="highlight"></span>
<span class="bar"></span>
<label class="form-label">Name</label>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
  background-color:#fff;
  padding:40px;
}

.group            { 
  position:relative; 
  margin-bottom:45px; 
}
.form-input                 {
  font-size:18px;
  padding:10px 10px 10px 5px;
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  border:none;
  border-bottom:1px solid #757575;
}
.form-input:focus       { outline:none; }

/* LABEL ======================================= */
.form-label                  {
  color:#999; 
  font-size:18px;
  font-weight:normal;
  position:absolute;
  pointer-events:none;
  left:5px;
  top:10px;
  transition:0.2s ease all; 
  -moz-transition:0.2s ease all; 
  -webkit-transition:0.2s ease all;
}

/* active state */
.form-input:focus ~ .form-label, .form-input:valid ~ .form-label        {
  top:-20px;
  font-size:14px;
  color:#d438c5;
}

/* BOTTOM BARS ================================= */
.bar    { position:relative; display:block; width:100%; }
.bar:before, .bar:after     {
  content:'';
  height:2px; 
  width:0;
  bottom:1px; 
  position:absolute;
  background:#d438c5; 
  transition:0.2s ease all; 
  -moz-transition:0.2s ease all; 
  -webkit-transition:0.2s ease all;
}
.bar:before {
  left:50%;
}
.bar:after {
  right:50%; 
}

/* active state */
.form-input:focus ~ .bar:before, .form-input:focus ~ .bar:after {
  width:50%;
}

/* HIGHLIGHTER ================================== */
.highlight {
  position:absolute;
  height:60%; 
  width:100px; 
  top:25%; 
  left:0;
  pointer-events:none;
  opacity:0.5;
}

/* active state */
.form-input:focus ~ .highlight {
  -webkit-animation:inputHighlighter 0.3s ease;
  -moz-animation:inputHighlighter 0.3s ease;
  animation:inputHighlighter 0.3s ease;
}

.form-select {
    height: 47px;
    background: transparent;
}

/* ANIMATIONS ================ */
@-webkit-keyframes inputHighlighter {
    from { background:#d438c5; }
  to    { width:0; background:transparent; }
}
@-moz-keyframes inputHighlighter {
    from { background:#d438c5; }
  to    { width:0; background:transparent; }
}
@keyframes inputHighlighter {
    from { background:#d438c5; }
  to    { width:0; background:transparent; }
}
```

Take a look at my js fiddle.
https://jsfiddle.net/97892awh/

Comment: So do want to remove the required, and what seems to changed in your css ?

Comment: @bhansa you tell me. I can't see anything that changes, but the animations become different. Check the fiddle.

Comment: I see the animation change, because you are checking for valid condition.

Answer (score 2):

That happens because of this selector:

`.form-input:valid ~ .form-label`

As you can see you have a `:valid` selector, which is triggered when the input is valid (obviously), in your case, when the input is `required`. Remove that and it will work:

```
.form-input:focus ~ .form-label{
  top:-20px;
  font-size:14px;
  color:#d438c5;
}
```

Example on [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/97892awh/1/).

Comment: There is one problem with this. If you remove valid, and enter a name in the input field, the label goes down and covers the text you entered. Try the fiddle and you will see.

Comment: Yes, of course it does, but you can make a workaround with Javascript. Check the input and if it's not empty, put a class to it like: `.not-empty` and style it accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the **`valid`** selector in your css if you don't want different css.

```
/* active state */
.form-input:focus ~ .form-label, .form-input:valid ~ .form-label {
  top:-20px;
  font-size:14px;
  color:#d438c5;
}
```

Comment: There is one problem with this. If you remove valid, and enter a name in the input field, the label goes down and covers the text you entered. Try the fiddle and you will see.

Comment: yes, I can see that. Let me check it again for that what needs to changed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved it.

Added a CSS class

```
.not-empty {
  top:-20px;
  font-size:14px;
  color:#d438c5;
}
```

And some jquery

```
$('#name').focusout(function() {
    var val = this.value;
  if (val.length > 0) {
    $('#name-label').addClass('not-empty');
  } else {
    $('#name-label').removeClass('not-empty');
  }
});
```

And also edited the HTML like this

```
<div class="group">
  <input type="text" class="form-input" id="name" autofocus>
  <span class="highlight"></span>
  <span class="bar"></span>
  <label class="form-label" id="name-label">Name</label>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/97892awh/3/